# AWS IAM Grant permission based on dynamodb attribute values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a dynamodb table which has following attribute values 

`| UserID | Name | paid  |
|--------|------|-------|
| 0001   | Sam  | false |`

I have a IAM polivy document written in a serverless yml file as follows

`- PolicyName: PaidPolicy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: "Allow"
                  Action:
                    - "s3:PutObject"
                  Resource:
                    - Fn::Join:
                        - ""
                        - - arn:aws:s3:::uploads
                          - "/protected/*"`

Is it possible to change the effect of the policy to `Allow` or `Deny` based on the `paid` column value

**Note:** I found that it is possible to add conditions using `Condition` attribute but could not find a way to refer the values of the dynamodb table

Answer (score 1):

Quick search through [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html) didn't amount to anything, so a solution I have in mind would be this:

1. Create user groups for paid and free users
2. Attach policies with allow and deny S3 actions to respective group
3. Create lambda function which will put user into said group based on column value in DynamoDB
4. Trigger lambda on DynamoDB table change via stream

Comment: I Really appriciate the answer :). But I am already using two user groups, one for the admins the other for the normal users and permissions and user roles accordingly. I am not sure how to manage roles if i add two more groups

Comment: Then maybe use IAM roles and require using those roles to access the bucket. Then lambda could update trust relationship of the role to allow this or that user to assume it. There are many ways to do this, hard to give a guess not seeing the setup.